# Uncle Bob's clean architecture - Composed entities

Tags: architecture, android, clean-code, architectural-patterns

I'm building an Android application, and trying to follow the Clean Architecture pattern.

I am a little confused on what my entities should look like regarding some of my use cases.

## Example

I have a list of channels, and each channel have programs.
I want to display a list of the current program for each channel, and when an element is clicked, I display a channel page with the channel detailed info and the current program info.

#### Entities

I can see here that I should have a Channel and a Program entity. But should Channel have a field `List<Program> programs` (as there are mutiple programs during the day)? And another `Program currentProgram`?
Or should Channel be separated

#### Use case

Should they return entities, or some dto object?
Currently, my use cases return entities, but are mapped to some dto objects in the presenters.

### TL;DR

Which of the proposition below is the way to go?

## Pseudo-Code propositions

## Case A

***Entities***

```
Channel
{
  id()
  name()
  logo()
}

Program
{
  id()
  name()
  thumbnail()
  start_date()
  end_date()
}
```

***Use Cases***
`List<Channel> GetChannelsUseCase()`
`Program GetCurrentProgramForChannel(channelId)`

***Presenter***

```
fetchChannels()
{
    // Builds a List<CurrentProgramViewModel> based on
    // GetChannelsUseCase composed with GetCurrentProgramForChannel for each channel
}
```

## Case B

***Entities***

```
Channel
{
  id()
  name()
  logo()
  programs()
}

Program
{
  id()
  name()
  thumbnail()
  start_date()
  end_date()
}
```

***Use Cases***
`List<Channel> GetChannelsUseCase()`

***Presenter***

```
fetchChannels()
{
    // Builds a List<CurrentProgramViewModel> based on
    // GetChannelsUseCase and filtering the programs()
    // to extract the 'current' program
}
```

## Case C

***Entities***

```
Channel
{
  id()
  name()
  logo()
}

Program
{
  id()
  name()
  thumbnail()
  start_date()
  end_date()
}
```

***Repository***
`List<Channel> GetChannelsUseCase()`
`Program GetCurrentProgramForChannel(channelId)`

***Use Cases***
`List<ProgramDto> GetCurrentProgramUseCase()`

```
{
    // The Use Case requests the repository to get the entities
    // and builds a ProgramDto object
}
```

***Presenter***

```
fetchChannels()
{
    // Maps a List<CurrentProgramViewModel> based on the
    // List<ProgramDto> returned by GetCurrentProgramUseCase
}
```

ps: I'll ask about the datasource and repository later / in another topic if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, a `Program` isn't permanently tied to a `Channel`.  In fact, a `Program` can appear on several `Channels` sometimes even at the same time!

I think you're missing a `Listing` entity which takes care of associating `Programs` with a specific time.  This means that your `Programs` should no longer track their start and end times anymore but they probably should track their `duration`.  You might benefit from a `Schedule` as well to link a `Listing` with a `Channel`.

**Pseudocode**:

```
Channel
{
  id,
  name,
  logo,
}

Program
{
  id,
  name,
  thumbnail,
  duration,
}

Schedule
{
  channelId,
  date,
  listings = Collection<Listing>
}

Listing
{
  program,
  startTime,
  endTime = () => startTime + program.duration,
}
```

You would then have a service that allows you to query `Schedule`s base on the channel and date.

Comment: What about the usecases though? Can/should they in fact return the entities?

Comment: I'm confused about this use of the term "use case". A use case isn't a class or grouping of code in your application. Rather, it's an example of how your application is used to accomplish something.

Comment: I meant "Interactor" :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a Presenter should have as little logic as possible, and only interact with a single UseCase.

In Uncle Bob's [sample](https://github.com/cleancoders/CleanCodeCaseStudy/tree/master/src/cleancoderscom), he actually passes the Presenter to the UseCase as a parameter.  (The UseCase accepts an interface OutputBoundary.)  The UseCase passes a ResponseModel to the Presenter which contains all of the information that the Presenter needs to know to build the ViewModel.  Overall, this is closest to your Case C.

*Note: I'm a bit unsure if that ResponseModel should contain entities or properties.*

And I second MetaFight's recommendation about the missing entities and avoiding the composed entity.